AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
Whenever I try to install any module in Python through the pip command, it gives
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?

I have tried all these commands:
pip install cryptography
pip3 install cryptography
python3-pip install cryptography
python3 -m pip install cryptography

None of them works and gives the same error and when I try these commands with sudo they say it is an externally managed command.
What is the solution for this i can not use a virtual environment every time. I want to be able to install modules on the system so that I do not have to install them again and again for every project I do.

What is the version of Ubuntu? Have you changed the default version of Python that the unnamed version of Ubuntu shipped with?

Ubuntu 24.04. I have python 3.12 .3 installed.
